# Install Jenkins on Ubuntu 18.04.4. Jenkins didn´t start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, ubuntu-18.04

**Information:**

After updating Java to version 8, I also installed Jenkins according to the steps defined below. When I tried to start Jenkins, it couldn't start. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.04.

**Steps to reproduce the problem**

The steps contain the procedure which one can use to install Jenkins with Ubuntu 18.04 with Java 8. Can these steps be used with Ubuntu 18.04.04?

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
    sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
    wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo apt-add-repository "deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/"
    sudo apt install jenkins
```

**Issue Overview after install**

```
jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-01-09 11:47:20 CET; 3min 6s
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 692 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=1/FAILUR

Jan 09 11:47:19 Jenkins systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Jan 09 11:47:19 Jenkins jenkins[692]: Found an incorrect Java version
Jan 09 11:47:19 Jenkins jenkins[692]: Java version found:
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins jenkins[692]: openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins jenkins[692]: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.2+
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins jenkins[692]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.2+13-
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins jenkins[692]: Aborting
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Control process exited, cod
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins systemd[1]: jenkins.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
Jan 09 11:47:20 Jenkins systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start Jenkins at boot t
lines 1-16/16 (END)
```

Answer (score 2):

You installed OracleJDK but Jenkins found OpenJDK

try

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GaRaOne, choosing correct Java version helped me:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java 
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```